# Unable to install CBLAS on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, libraries, c

I am trying to install CBLAS on Ubuntu, and am, as far as I can see, following the instructions in the README file that came in the folder. When I do a 'make all', I get the following errors that I just do not understand:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/ernieProject_C/pascalInpaintCodes/CBLAS/t                                                                                                             esting'
gfortran  -o xscblat1 c_sblat1.o c_sblas1.o ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a ../lib/cblas_LINUX                                                                                                             .a
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_srotg.o): In function `cblas_srotg': cblas_srotg.c (.text+0x1): undefined reference to `srotg_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_srot.o): In function `cblas_srot':cblas_srot.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `srot_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_sswap.o): In function `cblas_sswap':cblas_sswap.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `sswap_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_sscal.o): In function `cblas_sscal':cblas_sscal.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `sscal_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_scopy.o): In function `cblas_scopy':cblas_scopy.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `scopy_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_saxpy.o): In function `cblas_saxpy':cblas_saxpy.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `saxpy_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(sdotsub.o): In function `sdotsub_':sdotsub.f:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `sdot_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(snrm2sub.o): In function `snrm2sub_':snrm2sub.f:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `snrm2_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(sasumsub.o): In function `sasumsub_':sasumsub.f:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `sasum_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(isamaxsub.o): In function `isamaxsub_':isamaxsub.f:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `isamax_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(scasumsub.o): In function `scasumsub_':scasumsub.f:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `scasum_'
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(scnrm2sub.o): In function `scnrm2sub_':scnrm2sub.f:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `scnrm2_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [xscblat1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/ernieProject_C/pascalInpaintCodes/CBLAS/te                                                                                                             sting'
make: *** [alltst] Error 2
```

Here is the Makefile.in. I modified it a teeny bit, as per instructions. Here it is:

```
#
# Makefile.LINUX
#
#
# If you compile, change the name to Makefile.in.
#
#

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Shell
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

SHELL = /bin/sh

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Platform
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAT = LINUX

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Libraries and includes
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

BLLIB = ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a
CBLIB = ../lib/cblas_$(PLAT).a

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compilers
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

CC = gcc
FC = gfortran
LOADER = $(FC)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Flags for Compilers
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

CFLAGS = -O3 -DADD_
FFLAGS = -O3

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Archive programs and flags
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

ARCH = ar
ARCHFLAGS = cr
RANLIB = ranlib
```

The line I modified here was

```
 BLLIB = ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a
```

I just changed the path. And now there IS a cblas_LINUX.a in ../lib, so that is, I think, correct.

Please, any pointers to why I am getting these errors would be really helpful. Isn't CBLAS supposed to be self-contained? Why does it even show such undefined references?

Thank you for reading and for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

The recommended method is to install CBLAS as part of lapack, ATLAS or OpenBLAS. For complete instructions you may see [here](https://github.com/Foadsf/Cmathtuts/tree/master/LAPACK)

1. You need to first install BLAS either by `sudo apt-get install libblas-dev` or by compiling the original implementation:

   1.1. download latest version of the BLAS from http://www.netlib.org/blas/

   1.2. unarchive and go to the folder in the terminal and run make

   1.3. look for the file named `blas_LINUX.a` and save the address to this file
2. compile the netlib cblas:

   2.1. download CBLAS from the same page

   2.2. unarchive

   2.3. open the file Makefile.in

   2.4. look for the line `BLLIB = .../blas_LINUX.a`

   2.5. put the address you had in step one here

   2.6. go to the terminal in unzipped cblas folder and run make
3. look for the cblas.h file in the include folder and when you want to compile link gcc against this folder

Instructions from [here](http://avulanov.blogspot.nl/2015/03/cblas-compilation-as-shared-library.html). If looking CBLAS examples you may check [here](https://github.com/Foadsf/Cmathtuts/tree/dev/C_CBLAS).

Answer (score 1):

I tried following Foad's instructions, and thought I was close to being successful, but ultimately couldn't get the program to recognize that I had installed CBLAS.

I eventually came across the comment to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623578/installing-blas-and-lapack-packages), which led me to the solution that immediately worked for me, to just install it from a pre-existing package.

```
sudo apt install libopenblas-dev
```

I hope you still find this answer useful 8 years after you asked the question.

Comment: Well, I did find it useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable BLLIB to the location of your dynamic **lapack** library.

In case you are not aware of it, you can find out by using the following commands:

```
locate liblapack
```

If you have installed it properly, you should find it in

```
/usr/lib/liblapack.a
/usr/lib/liblapack.so
```

So make the following changes,

```
BLLIB=/usr/lib/
```

Then you can execute the following set of commands to compile.

```
rm Makefile.in
ln -s Makefile.LINUX Makefile.in
make all
```

Respond if you were able to compile it successfully.