# Installing BLAS and LAPACK packages

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, libraries

How to install BLAS & LAPACK in Ubuntu 14.04? When I am trying to install these packages with `apt-get install BLAS`:

```
Error occurred  
Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: how are you installing?

Comment: I recommend the OpenBLAS implementation (`sudo apt install libopenblas-dev`), which is as fast as it can get (take a look at benchmarks on the web). As a bonus, it offers a LAPACK implementation as well.

Answer (score 90):

There's a typo in @Maythux's answer: there should be no `e` in `liblapacke`.

A more minimalist set of packages can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

Also, if you're installing these to get `scipy` to install with `pip`, it may not be the complete solution (I failed to use `pip install scipy` in an ARM architecture Ubuntu 14.04 system).  I found success with `apt-get install python-scipy`, but it was an older version (0.13.3).  If you need a newer version via `pip`, you may also need:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

[I found this info on StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114276/682515)

Comment: This works for me in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Windows.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, the solution is

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

Answer (score 12):

In order to solve the administrator directory lock problem, search for processes.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try the commands to install

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libblas-doc checkinstall
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev checkinstall
sudo apt-get install liblapack-doc checkinstall
```

Comment: Should we be recommending removal of a lock file before confirming that it's actually stale? As well, what are all the `checkinstall`s for?

Comment: @hamx0r's answer is the one you want to use. This is no longer correct.

Comment: @Zanna when you fixed the typo here in 2016, you missed an identical typo just above it! (You'll need to fix it; I don't have enough rep to do so.)

Comment: @MarkAmery the package `liblapacke-dev` exists. `liblapack-dev` also exists though and I'm not sure which was intended...