# How to build and link BLAS and LAPACK libraries by hand for use on cluster?

Tags: apt, compiling, c++

I am making use of a partial pivoting function by the name of `gesv`. To get the libraries to make this happen in C++ I used a one line command from [Installing BLAS and LAPACK packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623578/installing-blas-and-lapack-packages).

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

Then I was able to link the libraries by adding the following to the compile instructions

```
g++ main.cpp -llapack -lblas
```

I got tremendous speed up on my laptop (Linux 2020), but when I started running on a cluster the method is extremely slow when running the same (large) case. I don't think both of the libraries are installed on the cluster. The code runs, so it seems like whichever one provides the speed increase is not on the cluster I am using.

Is it possible to build and then link the `lapack` and `blas` libraries by "hand" rather than doing the `apt-get` command?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### BLAS

- Download the latest version of  [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/)
- Open a terminal and go to the directory where you have it saved

```
tar -xvf blas-3.8.0.tgz  # unzip the blas source files
cd BLAS-3.8.0/ 
make
mv blas_LINUX.a libblas.a
mv *.a path/to/lib  # move the blas lib to the library you will be including at compile
```

---

### LAPACK

- Download the latest version of [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)

```
tar -xvf lapack-3.9.0.tar.gz
cd lapack-3.9.0/
cp make.inc.example make.inc  # use example make as make
make
cp *.a path/to/lib
```

---

Now that the libraries have been built, and are stored in `path/to/lib`, the short example code in the question can be compiled.

```
g++ main.cpp -L/path/to/lib -llapack -lblas -lgfortran  # compiles the code
./a.out  # runs the code
```